# Communication by standard I/O between two C++ programs

Tags: c++, pipe, std

I was looking for easy communication between two programs. Something comfy like Python `process.stdin.write()` but unfourtanely I have not found solution like that. I wanted to avoid pipes, but then I think it's not possible.

So there are two programs:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define PROGRAM_FOR_TESTING "radix.x"

int main()
{

    pid_t forked = fork();

    // 0 for read, 1 for write
    int child_pipe_fd[2];
    int parent_pipe_fd[2];

    // parent ->
    if (pipe(child_pipe_fd) < 0 || pipe(parent_pipe_fd) < 0)
        exit(1);

    if (forked < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Something has gone wrong during the fork()." << std::endl;
        _exit(1);
    }
    else if (forked == 0)
    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "./" << PROGRAM_FOR_TESTING;

        std::string path = oss.str();
        int n = 100;

        // redirect std i/o

        int c1 = dup2(child_pipe_fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(child_pipe_fd[1]);

        if (c1 != STDIN_FILENO)
        {
            std::cout << "err" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        int c2 = dup2(parent_pipe_fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(parent_pipe_fd[0]);

        if (c2 != STDOUT_FILENO)
        {
            std::cout << "err" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }


        // child
        if (execl(path.c_str(), PROGRAM_FOR_TESTING, (char *)0) < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "err" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // parent
        close(child_pipe_fd[0]);
        close(parent_pipe_fd[1]);

        int *returned_num;

        while (1)
        {
            std::cout << read(parent_pipe_fd[0], returned_num, sizeof(int)) << std::endl; // is always 0

            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

radix.x:

```
int main()
{

    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << 100 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

There is no any received data in the parent. I know like `std::cout` produces the text and not the binary data, but no data is received at all by the program.

Comment: You must create the pipe before forking.

Comment: Also your `read` might crash because you don't know where you're trying to store the data. When you use an uninitialized pointer, you're literally telling the computer "hey, store the data *here*" and pointing to a random memory chip that might have important data in it already.

Comment: @Quimby OH. I forgot that I guess. Thank you. Now I'm getting some returns by read(). 

@user253751 Thanks too for pointing the issue. Now when I got the `pipe()` to work, I can play with the read.